# Writing to persistent memory in PCIe

Tags: c, linux, memory, pci-e, persistent-memory

I want to read and write to a persistant memory(for testing now ddr is connected) in my PCIe device (FPGA) on an Intel Linux system.

The memory is exposed in a particular bar (say bar 2). How to access this persistant memory. I looked into examples in PMDK library, but I couldn't find any.

When I looked into [libpmem library](https://pmem.io/pmdk/libpmem/) I did find mapping api `pmem_map_file()` but there is no provision to select the bars.

Is it possible to use `mmap()` call? Currently I am using as shown below to access my bar using the uio driver. Do I need to make any changes to mmmap pmmem memory?

```
mmap(NULL, 3*1024*1024, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, uio_fd0, 2* 4096);
```

Can anyone suggest me some ideas about this.

Comment: `mmap(MAP_SYNC|MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE)` is documented in the man page for persistent memory.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: So , I just needs to mmap using the above flags with driver fd( I am using uio driver)

Comment: Probably?  Those `mmap` flags should be what libpmem uses under the hood.  If that works for what you're doing, then great.  If you're rolling your own accesses, make sure to `clflush` or `clflushopt` (or `clwb`) your stores where necessary, like libpmem would do for you if you use its helper functions.

Comment: got error while compiling : error: ‘MAP_SYNC’ undeclared and error: ‘MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE’ undeclared
i am using kernel version 5.6.8-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 and centos-release-7-8.2003.0.el7.centos.x86_64

Comment: Those were new in Linux 4.15 according to the man page.  If they're not defined, you maybe forgot to include a header?  Or else CentOS's user-space headers are behind the kernel version.  You'll have to investigate your system; I use Arch Linux which updates everything from upstream regularly.

Comment: i have included header #include <sys/mman.h>

Comment: it succesfully compiled after including #include <linux/mman.h> , but i am gettig an error on mmap while running mmap failed: Operation not supported, i am using my uio driver for mmap,                                                                                                
MAP_SYNC flag is supported only for files supporting DAX

Comment: Ok, that rules out your guess that libpmem or similar stuff could be useful.