# error: ‘MAP_SYNC’ undeclared and error: ‘MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE’

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, centos7

After adding the flags `MAP_SYNC | MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE` I am getting error during compile time on `mmap`. I have included the header file `<sys/mman.h>`

I am using kernel version 5.6.8-1.el7.repo.x86_64 on centos-release-7-8.2003.0.el7.centos.x86_64

```
mmap(NULL, mapped_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SYNC |MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE, uio_fd0, 2* 4096);
```

Comment: Also, are you developing a **kernel module** or a simple C program?

Comment: error: ‘MAP_SYNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: i am trying to develop a c program

Comment: i am trying to do persistant memory transaction after mapping with these fag to my pcie device bar

Comment: if i change the flag to MAP_SHARED its compiling properly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61936842/writing-to-persistent-memory-in-pcie

Comment: Ah, I see, that's my bad! I was looking at my system documentation and I have an older kernel version than 4.15. Sorry about that, those indeed seem to be valid flags.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which C library (and version) you are using, is it glibc?

Comment: gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)

Comment: That's the compiler version. I am talking about the *C library*, which one is it and which version? Post the output of `ldd --version`. In any case, have you tried to `#include <linux/mman.h>`? If you have the headers for the current kernel installed you should be able to find those flags there.

Comment: ldd (GNU libc) 2.17

Comment: it worked after including the header #include <linux/mman.h>

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. glibc 2.17 is quite old (2012) while Linux 4.15 is much more recent (2018). I'll translate my previous comment into an answer.

Comment: how to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Your C library version is older than your current kernel version. The `MAP_SYNC` and `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE` flags were introduced in Linux 4.15 (2018), while glibc 2.17 was released in 2012. If you have the kernel headers installed, you should be able to `#include <linux/mman.h>` for those values.

> how to upgrade?

It's not that easy. You should be able to update using `yum update`, but chances are that your glibc package is already up to date and the CentOS maintainers are just not upgrading the package for your specific CentOS release. This question is better suited on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or on [Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), I would suggest you to ask there.